# Rectangle intersection algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm

Hi I tried a question to check whether two rectangles intersect or not
I have written code if rectangles are parallel to x-axis

```
struct point 
{
 int x;
 int y;
};

struct rect
{
 struct point left;
 struct point right;
};

//1 - intersection
// 0- no intersection
int rectintersectioncheck(struct rect r1,struct rect r2)
{
    int x_check = (r1.left.x > r2.right.x || r2.left.x > r1.right.x);
    int y_check = (r1.right.y > r2.left.y || r2.right.y > r1.left.y);

    if(x_check && y_check )
    {
               return 0;   
    }
    return 1;
}
```

its working fine for this case but i am confused for algo in case of rectangle not parallel to x-axis
as only top left,right bottm points are givenn 
please help?

Comment: If the rectangle is not parallel to X axis (or y axis), and you are given only two points (top left, bottom right) then you are screwed because there are infinitely many rectangles that fit this description.

Comment: Should those values be top left and bottom right? As to the other issue you need to rotate the rectangles.

Comment: @ElKamina - That is not true. Those dimensions will be the extreme and therefore define the rectangle.

Comment: that's why i posted it here i didn't understand logic to solve this as "there are infinitely many rectangles that fit this description" for set of only top left,right bottom co-ordinates" if all points are knows then its easy job

Comment: Matrix (maths) see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_%28mathematics%29

Comment: How you can say its not useful/unclear ??

Comment: @Anshulgarg - WHo is that comment directed to?

Comment: @Ed Heal - If you're only given the two points, you don't know the rotation, so you still don't have sufficient information

Comment: @ Ed Heal , i am saying that to  ElKamina

Comment: @ShaneMacLaughlin - Logic - Those are two corners - a diagonal across the rectangle.

Comment: @Ed Heal, then the rectangle must be parallel to the x-axis, be a square, or a rotated rectangle who's possible orientation is limited to the relationship of its height to width.  e.g. squares at 45 degrees to the x axis.

Comment: @ShaneMacLaughlin =- rotate and translate both rectangles. Makes the maths easier

Comment: @Ed, say neither rectangle is parallel to the X axis, how exactly then do you calculate the height and width?  Maybe a worked example would be beneficial, based on two rectangles, neither of which is parallel to the X axis, using only four points as input.

Comment: @ShaneMacLaughlin - Just do a rotation of the two points - i.e. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Comment: @Ed, you still haven't said how you then get height an width for the rectangles, as per Goblin Alchemists diagram.  If neither of the rectangles is parallel to the x axis, their relative difference in orientation does not give you this.  You're still one dimension (i.e. rotation or height) short of a solution.

Comment: The two points at the end of the diagonal is a right angle.Despite the orientation a rectangle does have width and height - that is covered by the diagonal - it goes up and across.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous.  You could mean - "do any of the edges of the rectangles intersect?", or you could mean - "do the interiors of the two rectangles intersect (ie, have any common points)".  These two questions are NOT equivalent, so the solution will differ depending on which you mean.

Answer (score 1):

A clarification first. If p1 and p2 are the top-left and bottom-right points of a rectangle, then the rectangle *must* be parallel to x axis (and y axis). So there is only exactly one rectangle satisfying these conditions. If the rectangle is not parallel to x axis, then the bottom cannot become right point simultaneously.

Since we are talking about rectangles that are not exactly parallel to x axis, let us drop that definition. Let us talk about rectangles whose two opposing vertices are p1 and p2 (not necessarily top-left and bottom-right).

Let p1 and p2 define the first rectangle, and p3 and p4 define the second rectangle.

If you take the union of all rectangle whose opposite corners are p1 and p2, you get a circle (with (p1+p2)/2 as center and |p1−p2| as diameter).

There are three cases:

1. If the p1–p2 line segment intersects the p3–p4 line segment, then the rectangles always intersect.
2. If the circle corresponding to p1,p2 intersects the circle corresponding to p3,p4, then those rectangles *sometimes* intersect.
3. Otherwise those rectangles never intersect.

Comment: Please explain how circles are related to rectangles? Thanks

Comment: If you take the union of areas covered by all the rectangles that pass through two points (on the opposite corners) is a rectangle.

Comment: Eh- A circle is a different shape to a rectangle. So please explain how they are related.

Comment: @EdHeal A small geometry exercise: let p1 and p2 be the opposite corners of a rectangle. Let pc be the mid point between p1 and p2. Now, draw a circle with pc as center and p1-p2 as diameter. Let p3 be a point on that circle. Let p4 be the diagonally opposite point of p3 in that circle. It is obvious that p1-p3-p2-p4-p1 is a rectangle. Conversely you can also prove that is p1-p5-p2-p6 be a rectangle, we can prove that p5 and p6 are on that circle and are diagonally opposite. Therefore we can say that "union" of area of all the rectangles that pass through p1 and p2 form a circle.

Comment: But p3 and/or p4 may not be in the original rectangle. Just get a jam jar and plop it on a rectangle that you draw on some paper. Enjoy proving it.

Comment: @EdHeal What original rectangle are you talking about? With just two points there is no "original rectangle". I am talking about a family of rectangles.

Comment: Also where does p5 and p6 come from?

Comment: Please read the original question - two rectangles intersecting.

Comment: Just need two points to define a rectangle. The question is how to work out if they intersect.

Comment: @EdHeal Cut two rectangles from a piece of paper. Drop them onto your desk, not too far from each other, and give a mathematical description of the intersection condition _without_ a circle somewhere. Since two points only can describe a line, you have no idea about the direction of this line which you need to take into account when writing your test.

Comment: @EdHeal, please [look here](http://ib3.keep4u.ru/b/2012/09/12/bb/bb339260dc738d447afd073552def067.gif). These rectangles have the same top left and bottom right corners.

Comment: @GoblinAlchemist Thanks for image. That explains my point!

Comment: Hod to work out if two rectangles intersect? Using a circle where part o that circle falls outside. AS to dropping rectangles on the desk please invest in a compass. A circle from one rectangle does not cover and covers elsewhere space.

Comment: BTW _ That image does not have the same corners. top left of the red is not the same as the blue - and that is for starters.

Answer (score 0):

@ELKamina: the circle approach you discussed is quite fine, but it can be really hard to distinguish in the cases where cirles intersect but rectangles don't.

I have got his idea in mind, glad to share it.

Why don't we contruct our rectangles in array in the specific cases to find out they intersect or not.

```
 eg.  rect 1- points (1,3)(3,1)(6,4)(4,6)     rect2 points- (4,0)(5,0)(5,1)(4,1)
array represntation                                      array representation
6 [F F F F # F F F]                                      6 [F F F F F F F F]
5 [F F F # # # F F]                                      5 [F F F F F F F F]
4 [F F # # # # # F]                                      4 [F F F F F F F F]
3 [F # # # # # F F]                                      3 [F F F F F F F F]
2 [F F # # # F F F]                                      2 [F F F F F F F F]
1 [F F F # F F F F]                                      1 [F F F F # # F F]
0 [F F F F F F F F]                                      0 [F F F F # # F F]
   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7                                          0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

in the above case circles intersect but rectangles don't.

```
eg
g. rect 1- points (1,3)(3,1)(6,4)(4,6)     rect2 points- (3,0)(4,0)(3,1)(4,1)
 array represntation                                      array representation
6 [F F F F # F F F]                                      6 [F F F F F F F F]
5 [F F F # # # F F]                                      5 [F F F F F F F F]
4 [F F # # # # # F]                                      4 [F F F F F F F F]
3 [F # # # # # F F]                                      3 [F F F F F F F F]
2 [F F # # # F F F]                                      2 [F F F F F F F F]
1 [F F F # F F F F]                                      1 [F F F # # F F F]
0 [F F F F F F F F]                                      0 [F F F # # F F F]
   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7                                          0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

in the above case (3,1) has same value so it can be found that they intersect.
Similar representations can be used to check whether triangles intersect or not.

Answer (score -3):

I will sketch out the answer.

1. Rotate both the rectangles so that one is in line with the x axis
2. You can then work out the formula (y=mx+c) for the edges
3. You will also know the formula for the sides of the other rectangle
4. See if any intersect.

The rotation can be performed using the link previously posed.

**EDIT**

Forgot translation - shift one rectangle to have 0,0 as one coordinate.

Comment: but i don't know rotation angle as well so i have to check for every possible angle value?

Comment: You have two points. i.e. (x,y)*2 so use maths to work out the angle.

Comment: @Anshulgarg, if you don't know rotation then there is not enough source information to do anything. "Are the rectangles with unknown rotation intersecting?" The correct answer is: "I don't know". Please double-check what you really have.

Comment: @GoblinAlchemist - but this person has two points - i.e. a straight line - quite easy to figure out the angle. I vaguely remember doing this in maths as a 14 year old! Had graph paper to do it!

Comment: @EdHeal, a line between top left and bottom right is the diagonal, it is not the rectangle itself. You can imagine rectangles with different proportions and different rotations having the same two corners; the remaining two corners will of course be different. To define an arbitrary rectangle you need to know at least three corners.

Comment: @GoblinAlchemist - you can rotate the shape and do a translation. therefore the top left is known as well as the bottom right. It is matrix maths. Give me two points and I will compute the area of that rectangle.

Comment: Forgot to mention that a diagonal gives you both width and height. What more do you need to define a rectangle?

Comment: @Ed Heal, utter nonsense.  Diagonal gives you width and height if the rectangles base line is horizontal.  If you use the bearing of the line for rotation, then both points lie on the base of the rectangle and you lose height, either that or you're constrained to a very small set of possible rectangles.  e.g. all squares can only be rotated through 45 degrees.

Comment: @ShaneMacLaughlin - Rotate the rectangle. then the diagonal has a x component and a y component - i.e. width and height

Comment: Ed, you keep repeating "rotate the rectangle". But you can't rotate the rectangle because there is no such thing as *the* rectangle. You have an infinite amount of rectangles. Each of them at a different rotation angle. Each of them of a different size. You don't know which one is yours. Here is [a quick sketch](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BhZKb.png). One diagonal is simply not enough to define a rectangle — for the exact same reason that the hypotenuse is not enough to define a right triangle. @Shane is right. Goblin is right. ElKamina is right. You are wrong. Sorry.